# How to Get Last Four Number to String From Character Array in Mikroc Pro

Tags: mikroc

I have character array like bellow,

```
char ch1_on[]="0123456789";
```

I need to get last four number (6789) of above variable to int variable. how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

The function that you need is "memmove" from the MikroC library.

Its prototype is defined as: `void *memmove(void *to, void *from, int n);`

where `void *to` is a temporary char array (This will hold the substring 6789), `void *from` is your char array `ch1_on` plus the starting index of what you need to copy (In your case +6 because you want to copy the characters from index 6 to 9) and `int n` where 'n' is the number of characters to copy (which is 4 in your case; 6, 7, 8, 9).

So to work on it, you just need to declared a holder:

```
char converted[] = "0000";
```

and do a memmove:

```
memmove(converted, ch1_on + 6, 4);
```

and finally, use `atoi` to convert the substring to integer.

```
result = atoi(converted);
```

result will hold the final integer.

For more information, please refer to the help section of MikroC and search for 'memmove' under the ANSI C String Library topic.